# Apache Ignite - Unable to Connect to local node

Tags: java, ignite

I am trying to connect to a locally running Ignite Server (run via ignite.bat) from my Java App. The problem is strange! I am able to connect to all nodes running in VM Ware from windows 8. However without those VM ware Linux nodes running on the pc, I can't connect to the local running Ignite server. I am using 127.0.0.1 as an address in IP Finder but it says Failed to connect to any address from IP Finder. Here is my Java code -

```
TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
    List<String> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
    addressList.add("127.0.0.1:47500");
    addressList.add("192.168.25.1");
    addressList.add("192.168.1.101");
    addressList.add("192.168.56.1");
    addressList.add("192.168.10.1");
    addressList.add("localhost");

    ipFinder.setAddresses(addressList);
    tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
    tcpDiscoverySpi.setLocalAddress("127.0.0.1");

    OptimizedMarshaller optimize = new OptimizedMarshaller();
    optimize.setRequireSerializable(false);
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    cfg.setLocalHost("127.0.0.1");

    cfg.setClientMode(true);
    cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(false);
    cfg.setMarshaller(optimize);
    cfg.setMarshaller(optimize);
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi);
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

Comment: I ran your code and connection was successfully established. Could you please provide Ignite version you use, server node configuration and log message? Thanks!

Comment: I am using Ignite 1.4, default-config.xml and log is - Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (will retry to join topology every 2 secs): [/127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.1.101:47500, /192.168.10.1:47500, /192.168.25.129:47500, /192.168.56.1:47500, localhost/127.0.0.1:47500]

Comment: Unfortunately can't reproduce. I start one server node and one client node based on your code. Client connects to the server. Could you connect to 127.0.0.1:47500 using telnet for example?

Comment: I have a doubt that it's a Windows loop back issue. Can anyone confirm this? How do i test loopback with telnet?

Comment: I tested it under Windows and Linux and all work. Usually message "Failed to connect to any address from IP finder" means that there are no server nodes on any addresses from list. Please look at server node log. May it contains any helpful information.

Comment: It's reproduced for me. Oru, does it work if you provide local non-loopback address instead of 127.0.0.1?

Comment: No it doesn't work for any local ip. Also the server log is empty because nothing reaches it from local loops.

Comment: @Oru, were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: No! I switched to Debian to resolve this issue. It works and is much faster.